# Logstash csv filter create index name based on timestamp

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I want to create ES index based on the dates matching from the logfile. I am using logstash CSV filter to process the logs. For instance, the log data appears like below

```
2016-02-21 00:02:32.238,123.abc.com,data
2016-02-22 00:04:40.145,345.abc.com,data
```

Below is the logstash configuration file. Obviously the index will be created as testlog, however, i want the index to be created as testlog-2016.02.21 and testlog-2016.02.22, given that YYYY.mm.dd is the logstash preferred format for index dates. I have done this with grok filters, and I am trying the achieve the same with csv, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
filter {
 csv {
    columns => [ "timestamp", "host", "data" ]
    separator => ","
    remove_field => ["message"]
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            index => "testlog"
    }
}
```

We are on  Logstash 2.1.0, ES 2.1.0 and Kibana 4.3.0 version

Any inputs appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the @timestamp field in filter, and you also need to specify your index name as below:

```
filter {
  csv {
    columns => [ "timestamp", "host", "data" ]
    separator => ","
    remove_field => ["message"]
  }

  date {
    match => [ "timestamp", "ISO8601" ] #specify timestamp format
    timezone => "UTC" #specify timezone
    target => "@timestamp"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch 
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "testlog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```